# User Input as Argument C++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, user-input

I am new to coding and was wondering why my code is not acting the way I intended. I build the code as a training program to help me practice what i have learned. The code seems to work fine, as expected, when I comment out lines 19 - 23,the multi line comment section, but when I don't that's when it starts to act unexpectedly.

```
#include <iostream>

int askUserNumber ()
{
    std::cout << "Please input a number: " << std::endl;  //ask user to input number
    int userNumber;                                       //define integer to store input
    std::cin >> userNumber;                               // get input from user

    return (userNumber);                                  // return input to caller
}

void printUserNumber (int userNumber)
{
    std::cout << "Your number input was: " << userNumber << std::endl; //print input to user screen
}

int main ()
{
    /*
    std::cout << "Please input your name: " << std::endl;      // ask user name
    int userName;                                         // variable to store user name
    std::cin >> userName;                                 // get user name
    */

    printUserNumber(askUserNumber());                       // call to askUserNumber to get user input to print to screen
    return(0);
}
```

Results(Without Commenting out code):

Please input your name:  
Corey 
Please input a number: 
Your number input was: "someGarbageNumber"

It does't let me input a number at that part and it just prints out a random number.

Results(With Commenting out code):

Please input a number: 
7 
Your number input was: 7

This time it runs perfectly and there are no problems. I don't understand why the three lines asking for the users name cause it to not allow me to input a number when the function call for printUserNumber(askUserNumber()) gets to the point that it prints "Please input a number:" and doesn't allow me to input one. Thank you for any responses. I hope I wrote my question in a good format, and explained my problem in a clear and straight forward way. Hopefully the results will section will also allow for some clarity. Looking forward to a solution thanks again.

Comment: `userNumber` is an `int`. You can't store a string of text in an `int` (`"Corey"` is not an `int`). The text is still in the input buffer when you get the next input and it still fails to read as an `int`.

Comment: When you are prompted to enter your name, do you actually type in your name? That won't work, because you are attempting to read it into an `int` variable, `int userName`. Only a "name" that is parseable as an int would work.

Comment: A read of a non-numeric string into an `int` fails, so the `int` remains uninitialized (i.e. contains garbage).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `userName` is an `int` and you are trying to use `std::cin` to read a sequence of non-numeric characters into it, the operation fails and leaves `std::cin` in a [`fail()`ed state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_failbit) and so none of the following `operator>>` calls on `std::cin` will succeed in extracting further input characters.

> It does't let me input a number at that part and it just prints out a
>   random number.

Until C++11 the behavior was to leave the *rhs* unmodified, which in your case is an uninitialized `int`, hence the garbage you see when printing.

You can see all of that in the reference of [`std::basic_istream::operator>>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> - If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), 
>     `value` is left unmodified and `failbit` is set. (until C++11)
> - If extraction fails, zero is written to value and `failbit` is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in `value`, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` is written and `failbit` flag is set. (since C++11)

You can still recover from such `fail()` state in the stream by clearing its error state flags and ignoring what's in the buffer:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please input your name: " << std::endl; // ask user name
    int userName;                                         // variable to store user name
    std::cin >> userName;                                 // get user name

    if (!std::cin) // Check if `fail()`
    {
        std::cout << "input stream failure :-(" << '\n';

        // Clearing flags and input buffer
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your name input was: " << userName << '\n';
    }

    printUserNumber(askUserNumber());                       // call to askUserNumber to get user input to print to screen

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```xml
Please input your name: 
input stream failure :-(
Please input a number: 
Your number input was: 7
```

The solution to get your desired behavior is simply to make `userName` a `std::string` for example. In which case [the above code produces the output:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PmckXB5zU4RwdQjX)

```xml
Please input your name: 
Your name input was: Corey
Please input a number: 
Your number input was: 7
```